# call office 2010 Api from legacy c++ Application

Tags: c++, office-2010, visual-studio-6

i have a problem with an 15 year old c++ Application that uses an old office-api to create a .doc file and open it with word.

The Application includes the following files

**mso9.dll**
**vbe6ext.olb**
**excel9.olb**
**msword9.olb**

We are currently migrating from office 2003 to 2010 and windows xp to windows 7.

now we are experiencing some problems wenn opening the .doc file( "Cannot open temporary file" when there is already an open instance of word).

now i would like do change the included files mentioned above to the corresponding files from office 2010. i know that there are no *.olb files anymore but i had hoped that there is a symple dll i could import and everything works again.

Can anyone tell me if there is such an dll (and which) or if it is possible at all to get this application running without major changes. we would rather reimplement the whole application before spending much time to change the old one.

thanks in advance
Andreas

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the version of the type library you use.  Office simply prevents two users from modifying the same file, the first one wins.  The next one needs to set the ReadOnly argument of the Open() call to true.  Adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: This is no Multi-User issue. The File is localy created and opened via the application. The Problem occurs when the user has a word-instance open with a different file

Comment: Very hard to explain, you always create your own instance of WinWord.exe with COM.  Are you sure this an error generated by Word and not, say, GetTempFileName()?  I'd look for a mis-behaving macro or add-in.

Comment: I investigated a bit further now. i was mistaken as the application opens no .doc but uses a .htm file and opens it with word. when a word instance is already open this file seems not to be created at all. However the call to **CStdioFile.Open** returns true

Comment: This was my Problem:  
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?144980-Why-doesn-t-WaitForSingleObject-work&p=397600#post397600